# How do I get the program statement arguments like heightm passed down to other methods?

Tags: java, oop

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class CollinsHealthCalculator {

double ACTIVITY_FACTOR = 1.375;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    newHealthCalcDescription ();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("What is your weight in pounds? ");
    double weightlb = keyboard.nextDouble ();
    System.out.println ("What is your height in inches? ");
    double heightin = keyboard.nextDouble ();
    System.out.println ("What is your age in years? ");
    double ageYears = keyboard.nextDouble (); 
    double WEIGHT_KILOGRAMS = weightlb / 2.2;
    double HEIGHT_METERS = heightin * .0254;
    double weightkg = WEIGHT_KILOGRAMS;
    double heightm = HEIGHT_METERS;
    double computingBMI (BMI, weightkg, heightm);      
    maleBMR (heightm, weightkg, ageYears);
    femaleBMR (heightm, weightkg, ageYears);
    showResults (BMI, caloriesm, caloriesf);         

public static newHealthCalcDescription () {
    System.out.println("This calculator will determine your BMI "
            + "(Body Mass Index). While also it will determine the amount "
            + "of calories needed to maintain weight.");
}
    //Computing the BMI
public static void computingBMI (double BMI, double weightkg, double heightm){

    BMI = weightkg/(Math.pow(heightm, 2));

}
    //Computing BMR for male and female
public static void maleBMR (double heightm, double weightkg, double ageYears) {
    double HEIGHT_CENTIMETERS = heightm * 100;
    double heightcm = HEIGHT_CENTIMETERS ;
    double BMRForMales = 13.397 * weightkg + 4.799 * heightcm - 5.677 * ageYears + 88.362;
    double caloriesm = Math.round(BMRForMales * 1.375); 
}

public static void femaleBMR (double heightm, double weightkg, double ageYears) {
    double HEIGHT_CENTIMETERS = heightm * 100;
    double heightcm = HEIGHT_CENTIMETERS ;
    double BMRForFemales = 9.247 * weightkg + 3.098 * heightcm - 4.330 * ageYears + 447.593;
    double caloriesf = Math.round(BMRForFemales * 1.375);
}
public static void showResults (double BMI, double caloriesm, double caloriesf) {
    //Show results
    System.out.printf ("%nYour BMI is: %7.1f", BMI);
    System.out.println ("A BMI between 18.5 to 24.9 is considered normal.");
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("To maintain current weight:");
    System.out.print ("Men need to eat " + caloriesm);
    System.out.println (" calories per day.");
    System.out.print ("Females need to eat " + caloriesf);
    System.out.println (" calories per day.");       
}
```

}

I'm trying to get the code to pass down statements but I'm new to programming and have no clue on how to go about getting method passed down to another method. I've tried researching everywhere but I've had little luck in finding any help. Please help so I can make my programm functional I'm excited to learn just need help.

Comment: You might want to read up on [method parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Define 'program statement argument'.

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving the variables the global scope(outside the method). You may learn about it [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/field_variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable inside a method (i.e. code block), it is local to that block. So you cannot use that variable in any other method. Here the best option for you to do is to declare the variable, i.e. like weightkg etc as class variables.

Comment: What about now I tried taking the variables from main method and putting them inside the other method parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return type of the methods from void to double and store the returned result and send the results to other methods.
for eg.

```
public static double computingBMI (double BMI, double weightkg, double heightm){

  return weightkg/(Math.pow(heightm, 2));

}
```